# reading .txt file in python

Tags: python, command, line

I have a problem with a code in python. I want to read a .txt file. I use the code:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')  # We need to re-open the file
data = f.read()

print(data)
```

I would like to read ONLY the first line from this .txt file. I use

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')  # We need to re-open the file
data = f.readline(1)

print(data)
```

But I am seeing that in screen only the first letter of the line is showing.

Could you help me in order to read all the letters of the line ? (I mean to read whole the line of the .txt file)

Comment: After `f = open('test.txt', 'r')`, then `one_line = next(f)`.

Answer (score 5):

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
   print(f.readline())
```

This will open the file using `with` context block (which will close the file automatically when we are done with it), and read the first line, this will be the same as:

```
f = open(“file.txt”)
print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

Your attempt with `f.readline(1)` won’t work because it the argument is meant for how many characters to print in the file, therefore it will only print the first character.

**Second method:**

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
   print(f.readlines()[0])
```

Or you could also do the above which will get a list of lines and print only the first line.

**To read the fifth line, use**

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
   print(f.readlines()[4])
```

Or:

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
   lines = []
   lines += f.readline()
   lines += f.readline()
   lines += f.readline()
   lines += f.readline()
   lines += f.readline()
   print(lines[-1])
```

The `-1` represents the last item of the list

Learn more:

- [with statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/)
- [files in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp)
- [readline method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm)

Comment: I would like to read ONLY the 5th line. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your first try is almost there, you should have done the following:

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
line = f.readline()
print(line)
f.close()
```

A safer approach to read file is:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

Both ways will print only the first line.

Your error was that you passed `1` to `readline` which means you want to read size of 1, which is only a single character. please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp

Comment: I would like to read ONLY the 5th line. How could I do this?

Comment: @IvanRoma just iterate 5 times on the file, if you will call the `readline` method 5 times you will get the 5th line, or `f.readlines()[4]`

Comment: please leave a comment explaining why you downvoted my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works, after your suggestions:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()[1]

print(data)
```

Comment: You can “accept” or validate my (or someone else’s) answer if it was useful, just click the tick below the vote buttons - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Also please remember to `f.close()` to close the file when you are done with it, check my answer for more details

Answer (score -1):

Use `with open(...)` instead:

```
with open("test.txt") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep `f.readline()` without parameters.

It will return you first line as a string and move cursor to second line.

Next time you use `f.readline()` it will return second line and move cursor to the next, etc...